# calling function through pointer without allocating memory from object

Tags: c++, class, pointers, member-functions

I have a class as

```
class BTree {
    public:
    int val;
    BTree *next;
    BTree *child;
    BTree* putVal(int v) {
        BTree *temp = new BTree;
        temp->val = v;
        return temp;
    }
}*root;
```

can it be used as ?

```
root = root->putVal(12);
printf("%x %d\n",root,root->val);
```

Above printed root =0 before putVal call and some memory location after call.
It is probably very bad code but I just want to know is it allowed and will work as expected?

How are functions called ?

From calling syntax it appeared that each variable has a copy of pointer to functions in class. In that case this shouldn't work since memory is not yet allocated for object.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not allowed. The use of null pointers is not allowed, and "calling a member function" counts as use.

There are a few things you can do with null pointers which don't count as use. Comparing them with other pointers, and assigning new values are the two most common ones.

The underlying reason is that a null pointer doesn't point to an object, and calling a member function of an object does require an actual object.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is undefined behaviour - calling methods using a NULL object pointer is UB. However, to answer your question why does it work at all in your case - in most compilers only virtual functions addresses are stored in the object. Non virtual functions, such as your `putVal` are called in similar way as global functions, only they have additional hidden parameter pointing to the object.

In practice it means that if in many cases if you call a virtual function using a NULL pointer it will crash right away. If you call a non-virtual function then it will crash when first time the object is accessed in the body of the function (accessed means - a field is read or written, or a virtual function is called). Since your function does not access your object at all, there is no crash.

Again, what you have is UB and such code should never be used. Even with the implementation details described above (which may or may not be true) you do not want to make a function virtual, or update the compiler and get surprising crashes. But I guess it is worth it to understand how the usual implementation of method call in C++ looks like.

Answer (score 0):

As other peers have mentioned null pointer is not an object and trying to access member  functions causes crash, but PutVal function has the attributes to become an static function.

PutVal takes an int and makes an object from the argument. putVal do not do operations on the object rather initializes it.

Make the putVal static for a better implementation.